# .htaccess ForceType returning 404 Not Found

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http, httpd

I have a .htaccess file which contains:

```
<FilesMatch "^api$">
   ForceType application/x-httpd-php
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

This works on my local server but not on my actual host. When I try to access http://www.domain.com/api/path/info it just returns 404 Not Found, the output on my local server is $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and looks like it should. How do I resolve this issue at my host?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure why you'd need a `FilesMatch`, a simple :

```
<Files 'api'>
  ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

should do.

Then, you may need to check that your actual host has an `AllowOverride` set to at least `FileInfo` so that your .htaccess has the possibility to do the [`ForceType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype).

Comment: According to my host, AllowOveride All is set

Comment: And have you tried doing just a `<Files>` ?

Comment: Yep, still receiving Not Found

Comment: Well, there are a few possibilities left, either there's no `AllowOverride All` set, your host's not running apache, there's a something mispelled in your `.htaccess` file...
You should have a look at the error log see if there is something there.